# Basic boolean minimization

Tags: boolean-logic, algebra, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am trying to simplify the following piece of boolean algebra so I can construct the circuit :

```
A'.B'.C.D  +  A'.B.C.D'  +  A'.B.C.D  +  A.B'.C'.D +  A.B'.C.D  +  A.B.C'.D  +  A.B.C.D' + A.B.C.D
```

So far I have gotten it to :

```
(C.D) + (B.C) + (A.C'.D)
```

Is this correct?

I want to get the best possible minimization.

The steps I have went through so far are :

```
A'.B'.C.D  +  A'.B.C.D'  +  A'.B.C.D  +  A+B'+C'+D +  A.B'+C+D  +  A.B.C'.D  +  A.B.C.D' + A.B.C.D 
= A.A'(B'.C.D)  +  A.A'(B.C.D')  +  A.A'(B.C.D)  +  B.B'(A.C'.D)
= (B.C.D) + (B'.C.D) + (B.C.D) + (B.C.D') + (A.C'.D)
= (C.D) + (B.C) + (A.C'.D)
```

Can I do any more?

Comment: You should be able to apply Karnaugh maps to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your equation is actually:

```
X = (A'.B'.C.D) + (A'.B.C.D') + (A'.B.C.D) + (A+B'+C'+D) + (A.B'+C+D) + (A.B.C'.D) + (A.B.C.D') + (A.B.C.D);
```

I just ran this through [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com/) and it factored it down to:

```
X = 1;
```

So you might want to check your simplification work and/or check that you've given the correct equation.

However I suspect there may be typos in the original equation above, and perhaps it should be:

```
X = (A'.B'.C.D) + (A'.B.C.D') + (A'.B.C.D) + (A.B'.C'.D) + (A.B'.C.D) + (A.B.C'.D) + (A.B.C.D') + (A.B.C.D);
```

?

In which case [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com/) simplifies it to:

```
X = B.C + A.D + C.D;
```

Comment: Looks to be Logic Friday having a problem here.

Comment: I think it's actually typos in the original question, not Logic Friday. My guess is that the `+` s in some of the terms should actually be `.` s.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying - yes, probably.

Comment: I'm really sorry, of course yes they are meant to be .'s and not +'s ! Tired mind ! My apologies and thank you for the simplification ! :)

Comment: No problem - you might want to check out Logic Friday if you're doing any more of this kind if thing - it's Windows-only I'm afraid, but it's simple, free and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see that you could possibly do is distribute the "C" in the left two terms:

```
(C).(B+D)+(A.C'.D)
```

Or you could distribute the "D":

```
(C+A.C').D + (B.C)
```

*Response to Comment:*  The distributive law is described here: http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/.  See the information under heading "T3"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response ! How did you arrive at the solution : (C).(B+D) + (A.C'.D) ?

If the line was :
(C.D) + (B.C) + (A.C'.D)

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter too early ! I dont really understand that minimization, how did the D get distributed into the equation ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution (found by brute force):

(a+c).(b+d).(c+d)

Comment: Sanity check: I don't think C should even appear in the result, since we have both a `+C` and a `+C'` term.

Comment: @Paul R: Feel free to post a valid solution without the C argument.

Comment: see my edited answer, based on assumption of typos in question.

Comment: My assumption here was that the OP actually meant "A'.B'.C.D  +  A'.B.C.D'  +  A'.B.C.D  +  A.B'.C'.D +  A.B'.C.D  +  A.B.C'.D  +  A.B.C.D' + A.B.C.D"

Answer (score 0):

for simplifying boolean expressions use karnaugh maps. i think it is very much useful if we less number of variables. but if we have more variables then we can follow methods because this method is not that preferable.